# Symfony2 Entity properties loaded from db

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

So , i'm working on a news portal , and i have two entities :

1. News Entity (id,title...source)
2. Source Entity(id,title...)

In News Entity,field named 'Source' is an id to Source Entity;
So , i need to access Source Title when publishing news . I know there's posibility doing thing relationships ManyToOne . But i don't want do it , because it makes my life harder in some cases . Is there posibility to execute a Query in Entity ? like :

```
public function getSourceTitle()
{
    $query = ...;
    return $query->getScalarResult();
}
```

Can i do it ? or is there another posibility ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good practice to query insiide Entity class. Entity class should hold just fields, setters and getters, nothing else. So, if you want to query the db, and how are you planning to do it? Injecting EntityManager? Ok, If you really want to do it you can simply do it like this:

```
...

private $entityManager;

public function __construct(EntityManagerINterface $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

...

public function getSourceTitle()
{
    $sourceRepository = $this->entityManager->getRepository('VendorMyBundle:Source');
    $queryBuilder = $sourceRepository->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->....

    return $queryBuilder->getScalarResult();
}
```

and use it as `new MyEntity($entityManager)` on entity creation.. But, you should know that this is considered as very bad practice...